# Eclipse debugger error: Evaluations must contain either an expression...

Tags: eclipse, debugging, generics, breakpoints

```
private Binding createImplicitBinding(Key<?> key, boolean optional) {

    JClassType rawClassType = keyUtil.getRawClassType(key);

    if (rawClassType.equals(ginjectorInterface)) {
       return ginjectorBindingProvider.get();
    }
     ......
 }
```

For the above snippet, I set a break point at `if (rawClassType.equals(ginjectorInterface))` with condition `rawClassType==null`, hoping the thread will suspend only when it is fulfilled. But I keep getting the error:

> eclipse Evaluations must contain either an expression

Can anyone tell me why? By the way, JClassType is interface.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? This is annoying me... using Eclipse 3.7.x (Indigo)

Comment: @wrschneider are you using generics?

Answer (score 3):

It may be an Eclipse bug related to how its own parser handles generic types, like `Key<?>` above.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344856

The workaround doesn't seem to work for me, though - and doesn't seem to apply to your example either.